# Visual Studio- bin/development folder shows up in GIT changes tab

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, git-config

Every time I make changes(Modify Existing or adding new SSIS package) to one of the SSIS project, bin\development folder appears with all the SSIS packages in the GIT Changes tab within Visual Studio.
How can I make it to not appear in the GIT changes so I do not accidentally check in the bin\development folder? One time I did it and it messed the versions of the SSIS package.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a git ignore for the bin folder, no?

[Ignoring directories in Git repositories on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343646/ignoring-directories-in-git-repositories-on-windows#343734)  + https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Visual Studio it might look like the following

[image]

I'm a lazy heathen and let GitHub desktop do the heavy lifting (note, it should have been #IgnoreThis/ with a trailing slash)

[image]